# Relationships with pairs of interrelated models

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have 3 models in Django: *Person*, *Workfield* and *SubWorkfield*.

A `person` can have many `workfield`-s and many `subWorkfield`-s as well, but the `subWorkfield`-s must be related to their parent `workfield`-s ( which the `person` must be related to).

**So how do I enforce** that whenever a `person` is related to a `subWorkfield` then he must also be related to that `subWorkfield`'s parent `workfield`?

Here's what I have so far, but I don't think it enforces the relationship:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    workfield = models.ManyToManyField(Workfield)
    subworkfield = models.ManyToManyField(SubWorkfield)


class Workfield(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class SubWorkfield(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    workfield = models.ForeignKey(Workfield)
```

I need to have the `workfield`s and `subWorkfield`-s decoupled because a `person` can belong to a `workfield` without any `subWorkfield`-s.

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't any good way to do what you want purely with the table structure itself. However, if you do the following:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    workfields = models.ManyToManyField(Workfield)
    subworkfields = models.ManyToManyField(SubWorkfield)

    def add_subworkfield(self, subworkfield):
        if subworkfield.workfield not in self.workfields:
            return False
        else:
            self.subworkfields.append(subworkfield)    


class Workfield(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class SubWorkfield(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    workfield = models.ForeignKey(Workfield)
```

And then you will just use the `add_subworkfield` method when adding subworkfields to `Person`s.

Alternatively, inside of the `Person` model you could override the `save` method:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for subworkfield in self.subworkfields:
            if subworkfield.workfield not in self.workfields:
                return
        super(Person, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

If it's a small app and it's just you, the first way should suffice. However, if you're working on something larger with multiple people, overriding `save` would be a safety incase someone doesn't use the `add_subworkfield` method.